# Checking dir exist and dir contain won't work on dropbox api

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api

**DBRoulette.java**

```
private final String DATA_DIR = "/DataBase/";
```

Dropbox

**DownloadRandomPicture**

```
 public DownloadRandomPicture(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> api,
            String dropboxPath, ImageView view) {
    mPath = dropboxPath;
```

**doInBackground()**

```
Entry dirent = mApi.metadata(mPath, 1000, null, true, null);
 if (!dirent.isDir || dirent.contents == null) {
                    // It's not a directory, or there's nothing in it
                    mErrorMsg = "File or empty directory";
                    return false;
                }
```

this code is not working at `DownloadRandomPicture.java`
anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: what is the type of `dirent` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are using

```
final static private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.DROPBOX;
```

we should

```
Entry dirent = mApi.metadata(mPath, 1000, null, false, null);
```

but if we are using

```
final static private AccessType ACCESS_TYPE = AccessType.APP_FOLDER;
```

we should use

```
Entry dirent = mApi.metadata(mPath, 1000, null, true, null);
```

The difference is at the boolean at the dirent

Answer (score 1):

Try this, its useful for you...

```
 try 
    {
        Entry existingEntry = mApi.metadata("/" + SavedProperties.selectedAddress , 1, null, false, null);
        if(existingEntry.isDir)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Folder exists : " + existingEntry.fileName());
            uploadPictures("/"+SavedProperties.selectedAddress + "/");
        }
    } 
    catch (DropboxException  e) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"Folder does not exist..." + e.fillInStackTrace());
        try 
        {
            Entry createFolder = mApi.createFolder("/"+SavedProperties.selectedAddress);
            Log.d(TAG,"Folder created..." + createFolder.rev);
            uploadPictures("/"+SavedProperties.selectedAddress + "/");
        } 
        catch (DropboxException e1)
        {
             Log.d(TAG,"Create Folder DropboxException : " + e1.fillInStackTrace() );
        }       
    }
```